# Why does the scrollbar jump around when using a ListView.separated

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have the following build method

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 65,
        right: 45,
        top: 150,
        bottom: 65,
      ),
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return const SizedBox(
          height: 40,
        );
      },
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return Container(
          height: 305,
          color: Colors.red,
        );
      },
      itemCount: 40,
    );
  }
```

But when scrolling my scrollbar jumps around everytime new items load in. When I change to a ListView.builder and add a SizedBox in the itembuilder under the container this problem doesn't happen.

This is with flutter Flutter 3.7.6 and on the Web platform.

[image]

Comment: what happen if you provide width on container

Comment: The same thing happens when applying a width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , in my system it works..

```
ListView.separated(physics:ScrollPhysics(),shrinkwrap:true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 65,
        right: 45,
        top: 150,
        bottom: 65,
      ),
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return const SizedBox(
          height: 40,
        );
      },
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return Container(
          height: 305,
          color: Colors.red,
        );
      },
      itemCount: 40,
    );
```

Comment: I think using shrink wrap impacts performance though. 

https://dartcodemetrics.dev/docs/rules/flutter/avoid-shrink-wrap-in-lists

And I can get it to work by using ListView.builder which strangely enough also seems to have much better performance than ListView.separated. I was mostly wondering why it happens and having a solution that is just as performant as ListView.builder.